# Multiple API call with Observable.zip

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I develop a RSS reader Android app. I want to API call more than one but I can't. My code is here, What am I doing wrong ?

Note;

- Response will be XML as String dasd
- Request size may increase (maybe 10)

ArticleServisGenerator;

```
object ArticleServiceGenerator {

private const val FAKE_URL = "https://api.github.com"

private val interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
}

private val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
    addInterceptor(interceptor)
}.build()

private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(FAKE_URL)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build()

val service: ArticleService = retrofit.create(ArticleService::class.java)}
```

ArticleService;

```
interface ArticleService {

@GET
fun getArticlesFromRss(@Url url: String): Observable<ResponseBody>}
```

And Repository

```
class Repository {

fun getArticlesFromRss() {
    val request: ArrayList<Observable<*>> = ArrayList()

    // The number may increase here.
    request.add(ArticleServiceGenerator.service.getArticlesFromRss("https://commonsware.com/blog/feed.atom"))
    request.add(ArticleServiceGenerator.service.getArticlesFromRss("https://jfenn.me/blog/feeds/android.xml"))
    request.add(ArticleServiceGenerator.service.getArticlesFromRss("https://arunkumar.dev/feed.xml"))

    Observable.zip(request) { Any() }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe({
            print(it.toString())
        }) {
            print(it.toString())
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
fun getArticlesFromRss() {
    val request: ArrayList<Observable<ResponseBody>> = ArrayList()
    request.add(ArticleServiceGenerator.service.getArticlesFromRss("https://commonsware.com/blog/feed.atom").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
    request.add(ArticleServiceGenerator.service.getArticlesFromRss("https://jfenn.me/blog/feeds/android.xml").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
    request.add(ArticleServiceGenerator.service.getArticlesFromRss("https://arunkumar.dev/feed.xml").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))

    Observable.zip(request){ args -> Arrays.asList(args) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            print(it.toString())
        }) {
            print(it.toString())
        }
}}
```

Comment: Thank @ChitanSoni, save my day. Result is here; it[0]

Comment: Does this not execute each network call twice? once when adding it to the list since you're calling the method, and then a second time when .zip executes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable<List<String>> result = Observable.zip(
      observable1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), 
      observable2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), 
      observable3.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), 
  new Function3<ResponseType1, ResponseType2, ResponseType3, List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public List<String> apply(ResponseType1 type1, ResponseType2 type2, ResponseType3 type3) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(type1.data);
        list.add(type2.data);
        list.add(type3.data);
        return list;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This is not for multiple api calls

Answer (score 0):

Each Observable inside zip is executed sequentially. Add `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to each getArticles Observable and it will execute them concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify default scheduler.

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io))
```